# How to put an item of a list object to another list

Tags: java

I have two list, based on some condition of first List, I want to add it into the second list.

I want to put the record of i index to the new list,it is skipping from the line where I am doing the assignment.
newFeedDetailsList = (List)feedDetailsList.get(i);

List feedDetailsList = getFeedDetails();
        List newFeedDetailsList =new ArrayList();
        if (feedDetailsList != null || feedDetailsList.size() != 0) {

```
        // ************************************************************************88
        for (int i = 0; i < feedDetailsList.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < feedDetailsList.size(); j++) {

                if (feedDetailsList.get(i).getCircuitId().equals(feedDetailsList.get(j).getCircuitId())) {
                    if (feedDetailsList.get(i).getMeasurementMaxHourly() == feedDetailsList.get(j)
                            .getMeasurementMaxHourly()) {
                        if (feedDetailsList.get(i).getMeasurementDirection().equals("Ingress")) {
                             newFeedDetailsList = (List<BandwidthAlertFeedDetailDTO>)feedDetailsList.get(i);
                        } else {
                            newFeedDetailsList = (List<BandwidthAlertFeedDetailDTO>) feedDetailsList
                                    .get(j);
                        }
                    } else if (feedDetailsList.get(i).getMeasurementMaxHourly() > feedDetailsList.get(j)
                            .getMeasurementMaxHourly()) {
                     newFeedDetailsList = (List<BandwidthAlertFeedDetailDTO>) feedDetailsList
                                .get(i);

                    } else {
                    newFeedDetailsList = (List<BandwidthAlertFeedDetailDTO>) feedDetailsList
                                .get(j);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

}

And my BandwidthAlertFeedDetailDTO class is defined as below with getters and setters.
public class BandwidthAlertFeedDetailDTO {

```
private Long rowId;
private String feedId;
private Long gcpOrgId;
private String serviceName;
private Long circuitPok;
private String circuitId;
private Long locationId;
private Long addressId;
private Timestamp alertGeneratedOn;
private String granularity;
private String measurementType;
private String measurementDirection;
private String measurementPeriod;
private Date measurementStartDatetime;
private Date measurementEndDatetime;
private int threshold;
private int thresholdMetCount;
private Timestamp alterExpiryOn;
private String status;
private String thresholdConfigType;
private int measurementMaxHourly;
private String emailNotificationTransactionId;
private Timestamp emailNotificationSentTs;
private String textNotificationTransactionId;
private Timestamp textNotificationSentTs;
```

}

I want to know how can I assign the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to cast a `BandwidthAlertFeedDetailDTO` object to a `List<BandwidthAlertFeedDetailDTO>` object. That's not possible, the object is of type `BandwidthAlertFeedDetailDTO` and is not a list. What you have to do is create the new list you want to fill and use the `add()` method on that list to add the object you want to add to the list. The code should look something like this:

```
List<BandwidthAlertFeedDetailDTO> newFeedDetailsList = new ArrayList<BandwidthAlertFeedDetailDTO>();
...
for loops here {
    ...
    BandwidthAlertFeedDetailDTO some_object_you_want_to_add = feedDetailsList.get(...);
    ...
    newFeedDetailsList.add(some_object_you_want_to_add);
    ...
}
```